# Extracting specific string from spreadsheet cell

Tags: regex, libreoffice-calc

I've got an LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet and need to extract a small string from a cell in each row.  The cells contain about a paragraph of text and look similar to the below but all with different words, lengths etc.  The one common thing is the actually the format of the text I need to extract, in this case `17/11/2016 09:00` but could be any date/time formatted like that in 24h format.

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the `17/11/2016 09:00` industry's
>   standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took
>   a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

I've searched the following site but can't join it together to work to even match let alone extract the actual string.

http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: I managed to get a regular expression to work: =COUNTIF(A1:A6,"^(?=\d)(?:(?:31(?!.(?:0?[2469]|11))|(?:30|29)(?!.0?2)|29(?=.0?2.(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(?:\x20|$))|(?:2[0-8]|1\d|0?[1-9]))([-./])(?:1[012]|0?[1-9])\1(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d\d(?:(?=\x20\d)\x20|$))?(((0?[1-9]|1[012])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}(\x20[AP]M))|([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$")  but it only works if the contents fo the cell are an exact match and I haven't a clue how to extract the matching string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula:

```
=MID(A1,SEARCH("[:digit:]{2}/[:digit:]{2}/[:digit:]{4} [:digit:]{2}:[:digit:]{2}",A1,1),16)
```

The result:

```
17/11/2016 09:00
```

The explanation:

- [MID](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Text_Functions#MID) grabs part of the text.
- `A1` is the cell containing the text.
- [SEARCH](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_SEARCH_function) gets the location of the text to grab.
- `[:digit:]{2}` looks for two digits.  Syntax is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/List_of_Regular_Expressions.
- `/` looks for a literal slash, as does the space () and a colon `:`.
- `1` starts looking at the beginning.
- `16` is the length of the text to grab.

For this to work, be sure regular expressions are enabled in Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice Calc -> Calculate -> `Enable regular expressions in formulas`.

Comment: "*For this to work, be sure regular expressions are enabled in...*" those like you, who are talking about the prerequisites are intelligent and helpful persons saving a lot of time to those who are not aware of such options.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative but similar approach that does not require a formula and returns a date/time index rather than text is to Find and Replace (Edit menu) using for Find:

```
(.*)([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})(.*)
```

and checking `Regular expressions` under `Other options`.

There are three (groups): anything before what we want, what we want and anything after what we want and the the replacement is of only the second capture group, so for Replace using:

```
$2
```

The patter to match is `{2}` of any numeric character (`[0-9]`) followed by `/`, another two numbers and forward slash, four numbers, space, another two numbers, `:`, and two numbers.

If data is in ColumnA the Find/Replace may be on a copy in ColumnB, to preserve the source data.